# Query Timeout in EF Core but runs fast in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a use case in which I am passing a query to a function and then doing some calculations. The query is formed based on what filters I pass. Below is the sample code

```
var totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

var limitExceeded = limit.HasValue && totalCount > limit.Value;
var pagedResults = new List<R>();
// Don't execute the query if the limit has been exceeded
if (!limitExceeded)
{
    //Do some work here
}
```

The problem I am facing is that there is a filter named 'filename' and when I pass that filter the underlying query that gets generated is given below

```
DECLARE @__fileName_1 nvarchar(1024) = N'%cmder.zip%';

SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[CreatedByUserId], [d].[DateCreated], [d].[DateModified], [d].[DatePurged], [d].[Deleted], [d].[DocumentKey], [d].[DocumentStatusId], [d].[DocumentTypeId], [d].[FileDesc], [d].[FileExt], [d].[FileLength], [d].[FileLengthTypeId], [d].[FileName], [d].[FileSize], [d].[FullPath], [d].[Hidden], [d].[ModifiedByUserId], [d].[PurgedByUserId], [d].[RepositoryId], [d].[SHA1], [d].[TransactionId], [d].[UploadedDate], [c].[Id], [c].[CaseId], [c].[DateModified], [c].[Deleted], [c].[DocumentId], [c].[ModifiedByUserId], [c].[PublishToId], [c].[TransactionId], [c0].[Id], [c0].[CaseCoordinatorId], [c0].[CaseName], [c0].[CaseNo], [c0].[CaseTypeId], [c0].[CaseVenueTypeId], [c0].[County], [c0].[Court], [c0].[DateModified], [c0].[DateSettled], [c0].[Deleted], [c0].[Disabled], [c0].[FullCaseName], [c0].[IsComplex], [c0].[IsDepository], [c0].[ModifiedByUserId], [c0].[NameKey], [c0].[Remarks], [c0].[SalesRepId], [c0].[TransactionId], [c0].[TrialDate], [c0].[USStateId], [l].[Name] AS [PublishTo], N'Case' AS [Level]
FROM [Documents].[Document] AS [d]
INNER JOIN [Orders].[CaseDocument] AS [c] ON [d].[Id] = [c].[DocumentId]
INNER JOIN [Orders].[Case] AS [c0] ON [c].[CaseId] = [c0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Admin].[LookupValue] AS [l] ON [c].[PublishToId] = [l].[Id]
WHERE [d].[FileName] LIKE @__fileName_1
ORDER BY [d].[UploadedDate] DESC
```

Now this query runs very fast on the SQL Server Management Studio but when I debug my C# code and as soon as the execution hits `await query.CountAsync()` its starts loading on the UI and then after a certain period it times out. Can someone help me debug this? When I send other filters like date it works fine but when I send name its then when its starts taking time but only on the C# side as I have checked that the generated query runs pretty fast.

Comment: `LIKE @__fileName_1` when `@__fileName_1 = N'%cmder.zip%'` is always going to be slow, because it requires an entire table scan. You want to avoid search for a string within a string because no indexes can be used.

Comment: @DaleK oh, they (an index that involves that column) can be *used* for an index scan, but: not *as optimally* as a seek

Comment: @MarcGravell true! And that can still save a lot of disk access, I've used that technique myself.

Comment: How many rows have you go in the Document table? The like %...% syntax makes it non sargable which means as others have said it will have to scan the whole table. You can make it faster by searching for the beginning like N'cmder.zip% and this is sargable so it can use an index if one is on the FileName column.

Comment: when something is fast in SSMS and slow via ADO.NET, it is usually down to *either* different query options (SSMS has different defaults to ADO.NET), or parameter sniffing - either way, the problem being that when you run it in SSMS you're getting a different query plan; see https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html; adding an `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` may help it at least be consistent (although that should also be used cautiously)

Comment: @DaleK ok so I already have an non clustered index on the filename column to help improve the search performance so what exactly should I do at the c# side to improve the performance ?

Comment: I would like to second what @MarcGravell just said. I hade the exact same issue. I ran a query against a table with a couple of million rows with different parameters. Because of parameter sniffing it caused a great perfomance issue. I solved it by running `EXEC sp_recompile [Table]` between each query. This was a one-time-thing and may not be appropriate in a production environment.

Comment: @Andrew there are a lot of rows and the query you see above is generated by ef core so I have no control over that, do you know of a way in linq I can do that ?

Comment: if it is being generated by LINQ, it gets *really* hard to do things like add hints; my view there: LINQ is great *when it works perfectly*; the moment it starts giving you grief: *stop doing that* - take the generated query you have, and use either EF raw APIs or Dapper to execute that query *with whatever tweaks you need*

Comment: @Shubham Tiwari try something like this

`YourDocuments.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.FileName, $"{yourSearchString}%"))`

This should work, you are seeing the limitations of the framework(s), I sometimes just write a stored proc instead of abstracting away what should be simpler :)

Comment: In the mean time, the count query is not the same as the SQL you show.

Comment: @GertArnold 'query' refers to the exact query that I have written. query.CountAsync() is the point when that query gets executed.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari, so this is different queries. Your query should contain COUNT(1) as single select column.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yeah I get your point but the issue here is mainly focused around the query that is being generated right ? i.e. the Like operator being used on the filename column and thus when ef core runs it sql selects a different execution plan for some reason and its definitely not optimal.

Comment: You can do nothing with LIKE here. Try to enable FullText Search. Or separate FilleName from full path.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv sorry I don't have idea about that can you give some reference on how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Well, FullText search has limitation what to search, and probably will not suits to this case. What about splitting `FileName` to two fields: `Path` and `FileName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to you having lots of rows in your Document table, you are doing a non-sargable scan of the whole table! which is not ideal. Ideally you want to make it sargable so remove the leading or trailing % signs.

e.g. if you remove the leading % then it will be able to use an index on the FirstName column (as long as you create one).  It can then seek to matches and just read that data and not the whole table.

You can try something like this in your linq code

```
YourDocuments.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.FileName, $"{yourSearchString}%"))
```

If you want more control consider a stored procedure, but if this does the job then all good :)

If you just created an index on the FileName and kept the %...% syntax, It may use the index as mentioned by others above, it would still be a full scan of that index. The index will be smaller than the clustered index table, hence why SQL Server would use it, because it will do less logical page reads.

Comment: so are you telling me that even if i have a non clustered index on the filename in my table if the search is like 'Like %xxx%' then it wont use that index ? and it would only use when I remove the leading % ?

Comment: It may use the index, but it will still be a full scan, (updated answer at bottom) as anything surrounded with %...% make is non-sargable and you then have to scan all rows. If you can filter the results more before hand like seek to a date range or user id then you could limit the full table scan, but it would still have to scan every row that is a match based of previous filtering. to quote brent ozar, its all about "selectivity" so if you can select the smallest data set and seek into that, the query will be faster.

Comment: Was this any use or have we not provided what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Andrew thanks for the answer, it did work and the performance increased drastically but there was a slight problem to that approach. The issue being that %abc% would have searched for all the string containing abc but abc% will only search for strings that starts with abc rather containing abc.